# SELECT INNER JOIN over two tables not pulling out any data

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull the same data from two tables.  One table is the previous months' data and is called MAArchive and the ManualAdjustment table is the current month.  I want to run a query that pulls out the same data from both tables depending on PTLName that is selected from the dropdown list.

I have created the below query but when it runs it doesn't pull any data from the table and no errors.

```
SELECT DISTINCT maarchive.ptlname, 
                maarchive.campusoccurred, 
                maarchive.deptoccurred, 
                maarchive.coursedetails, 
                maarchive.dateoccurred, 
                manualadjustments.ptlname        AS Expr1, 
                manualadjustments.campusoccurred AS Expr2, 
                manualadjustments.deptoccurred   AS Expr3, 
                manualadjustments.dateoccurred   AS Expr4 
FROM   maarchive 
       INNER JOIN manualadjustments 
               ON maarchive.maindex = manualadjustments.maindex 
                  AND maarchive.ptlname = manualadjustments.ptlname 
WHERE  ( maarchive.ptlname = @PTLName )
```

Comment: Either nothing matches the `ON` clause or nothing matches that `WHERE` clause.  That is why this query would return no rows.

Comment: Or one of the table is empty...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you are right Gordon, I have nothing to connect the INNER JOIN with.  As the MAIndex are different for each adjustment submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FULL OUTER JOIN
```

May be what your looking for in that case.

Heres a great explanation of joins and how they work.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

You ca try this syntax:

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
INTERSECT
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

The SQL INTERSECT operator is used to return the results of 2 or more SELECT statements. However, it only returns the rows selected by all queries or data sets. If a record exists in one query and not in the other, it will be omitted from the INTERSECT results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.ptlname, a.campusoccurred, a.deptoccurred, a.coursedetails, a.dateoccurred, 
       ma.ptlname AS Expr1, ma.campusoccurred AS Expr2, 
       ma.deptoccurred AS Expr3, ma.dateoccurred AS Expr4 
FROM maarchive a LEFT JOIN
     manualadjustments ma
     ON a.maindex = ma.maindex AND
        a.ptlname = ma.ptlname 
WHERE a.ptlname = @PTLName;
```

Then you can investigate why things don't match.

Based on your description, I don't see why `SELECT DISTINCT` would be necessary.